# Store rendered view file in a variable in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to store the resultant of a rendered view file inside a PHP variable instead outputting it to the the browser?

e.g.

```
$html = $this->load-view('path/view_file');
```

The reason I am asking is because in this particular situation I want to use the view file as a template (which has embedded PHP). I know there are better ways for templating, but in this particular situation it will not be convenient or efficient to redo how templating is carried out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible. set the third parameter to `TRUE`:

```
$html = $this->load-view('path/view_file', NULL, TRUE);
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't know how I missed that from the guide